# Resize WebPage to view all Elements without ScrollBars

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make the contents in my web page to be automatically resized so that at each resize level I can see all the contents of the webpage at once without using the scroll-bars. Is there a way with Bootstrap too?

Comment: Without any code that is a very vague question.  It sounds like you would need to start with responsive design and media queries, and yes Bootstrap can handle this.  It all depends at what level you are at in your knowledge.  Try some tutorials in this direction.  If this reply isn't accurate, please give more detail and possibly some code.

Comment: The point is can you actually make a webpage fit in its contents without the scrollbars. Such that if you want to view an item you zoom into it, not using scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

If you create this css class and add it over all of your elements it should work:

CSS:

```
.height-responsive {
    width: auto;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div class="height-responsive">
          //your code
       </div>
    </body>
```